# How to handle JSON returned validator errors in Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, json, laravel, laravel-4

have my form submitting via AJAX and returning the errors from the validator but not sure how to access them.

So I am returning the errors like so in my controller:

```
$validator = Validator::make($data, $rules, $messages);

if ($validator->fails()) {
  return Response::json(array(
    'errors' => $validator->messages()->all(),
    200)
  );
}
```

And (using firebug) I see the JSON is:

```
errors: Array
  0: "This field is required"
```

And so on. Im looking for a way to handle all possible errors and display them to the user.

Normally I would return in my controller:

```
'empty-field' => true
```

And then in my AJAX call:

```
success: function(data) {
  if(data.empty-field == true) {
    // inform the user of failure
  }
}
```

But this will soon become tedious checking for and sending every possible error via JSON. Any way I can simply check for any errors returned and handle them? Much like the way Laravel handles errors when not using AJAX:

```
@if($errors->has('field'))
  <p class="input-message input-error full-width">{{ $errors->first('field') }}</p>
@endif
```

Thanks.

Comment: You have to set the HTTP status to one of the Error Codes. Like 400. Then use the ajax `error` callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With JS `data.empty-field` is `data.empty substract field`, you should use `data['empty-field']`

And as in Laravel templates, you can count errors : errors.length without check each one.

```
success: function(data) {
  if(data.errors.length) {
    alert('There are ' + data.errors.length + ' errors');
  }
}
```